# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator#0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Spring AOP AspectJ Annotation Example
using @Before

Using 
Java 1.8
eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

- spring jar
- aopalliance-1.0jar
- aspectjrt 1.6.8
- aspectweaver 1.6.2
- cglib-3.2.6
- spring-aop-4.3.9

1. Operation class

   ```
   package com.rks.beans;
   public class Operation 
   {
       public void msg()
       {
           System.out.println("msg method invoked");
       }
       public int m()
       {
           System.out.println("m method invoked..");
           return 2;
       }
       public void k()
       {
           System.out.println("k method invoked..");
       }
   }
   ```
2. TrackOperation.java class

   ```
   package com.rks.beans;
   import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
   @Aspect
   public class TrackOperation
   {
       @Pointcut("execusion(* com.rks.beans.Operation.*(..))")
       public void k() //poincut name
       {

       }
       @Before("k()")//applying poincut on before advice
       public void myadvice(JoinPoint jp)
       {
           System.out.println("Addition concern");
       }
   }
   ```
3. spring.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">  

       <bean id="opBean" class="com.rks.beans.Operation">   </bean>  
       <bean id="trackMyBean" class="com.rks.beans.TrackOperation"></bean>  

       <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator"></bean>  

   </beans>
   ```
4. Test class

   ```
   package com.rks.test;

   import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
   import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

   import com.rks.beans.Operation;

   public class Test 
   {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
         ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/rks/resources/spring.xml");
         Operation e=(Operation)context.getBean("opBean");
         System.out.println("Calling msg");
         e.msg();
         System.out.println("Calling m");
         e.m();
         System.out.println("Calling k");
         e.k();
       }
   }
   ```

Error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [com/rks/resources/spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:892)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.rks.test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJPrecedenceComparator.<init>(AspectJPrecedenceComparator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<clinit>(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE error caused by falling into 1 of 2 cases:
- No bean
- More than 1 bean (2, 3 or 4 beans for only 1 class)
I see you used both **spring-aop-4.3.9** and **aopalliance-1.0jar**. Try to remove **aopalliance-1.0jar** and run again.
Another thing that looks very much like a version mismatch. Are you sure that all of your Spring jars are the same version?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its vesion problem.

Comment: @Sandy It's very nice if you vote for me 1 vote, I need 50 reputations to comment everywhere now :D